# How to dynamically add validations to material forms in Angular (v6)?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6

I have a form whose `field names` and `required validators` will change based on the `form type` (content_type) selected. On selecting the form_type, I get a list of `required_fields` and `optional_fields`, accordingly, I need to add Validators.required, so i can disable the submit button if the form is not filled properly.

After adding logic, i get following errors:

> this.form._updateTreeValidity is not a function

and

> this.form.get is not a function

and the form ends up [looking empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hu4dI.png) with the [following errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NS6X8.png). If i just keep fields without any formControlName or validations it looks [perfectly fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ISQe.png).

### Code

**Sample form fields**

```js
formFields = {
    required_fields: {
        actual_content: "Content",
        name: "Name",
        contact: "Phone Number"
    },
    optional_fields: {
        additional_content: "Additional card content",
        website: "Website URL",
    }
};
```

**form.component.ts**

```js
formGroup: FormGroup;

ngOnInit() {
    this.selectedType = 'text';
    this.service.getFormFields(this.selectedType)
                      .subscribe((data: {required_fields, optional_fields }) => {
                        // create array of field names to display in template
                        this.fieldNames = Object.assign(data.required_fields, data.optional_fields);
                        // create dynamic formGroup, with proper validators
                        this.formGroup = this.createGroup(data);
                        console.log({FormGroup: this.formGroup});
                      });
}

createGroup(formFields): FormGroup {
    const group: any = {};

    // required fields
    const reqFields = Object.keys(formFields.required_fields);
    reqFields.forEach(field => {
      group[field] = new FormControl(``, [Validators.required]);
    });

    // optional fields
    const optFields = Object.keys(formFields.optional_fields);
    optFields.forEach(field => {
      group[field] = new FormControl(``);
    });
    return group;
}

// the dynamically generated formGroup might look like
// formGroup = new FormGroup({
//   actual_content: new FormControl(``, [Validators.required]),
//   name: new FormControl(``, [Validators.required]),
//   contact: new FormControl(``, [Validators.required]),
//   additional_content: new FormControl(),
//   website: new FormControl(),
// })
```

**form.component.html**

```html
<form novalidate class="mainForm" [style.fontSize.px]="15" [formGroup]="formGroup" #myForm="ngForm">
    <div>
    <h3 class="sHeading"> Select Form Type </h3>
    <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="formField">
        <mat-select placeholder="Select Form Type" formControlName="content_type">
            <mat-option 
                #formType
                class="option" 
                *ngFor="let type of formTypes" 
                [value]="type.type"
                (click)="updateFormType(formType.value)">
            {{type.type}}
            </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
    </div>

    <div>
    <h3 class="sHeading"> {{fieldNames.name}} </h3>
    <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="formField">
    <input matInput 
            placeholder="Name should have 3 characters min." 
            formControlName="name">
    </mat-form-field>
    </div>

    <div>
    <h3 class="sHeading"> {{fieldNames.content_url}} </h3>
    <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="formField">
    <input matInput 
            placeholder="Provide Valid URL" 
            formControlName="content_url">
    </mat-form-field>
    </div>

    <div>
    <h3 class="sHeading"> {{fieldNames.actual_content}} </h3>
    <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="formField">
    <textarea 
            matInput 
            placeholder="Describe the content"
            rows=6
            formControlName="actual_content"></textarea>
    </mat-form-field>
    </div>

    <div>
    <h3 class="sHeading"> {{fieldNames.additional_content}} </h3>
    <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="formField">
    <textarea 
            matInput 
            placeholder="Describe the additional content"
            rows=6
            formControlName="additional_content"></textarea>
    </mat-form-field>
    </div>

    <div>
        <button mat-raised-button type="submit" class="submitBtn" [disabled]="!myForm.valid">Submit</button>            
    </div>
</form>
```

### Question

What is the correct way to add validationss dynamically?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have several issues, I don't know if it's because you have changed some variable/prop names for the question, but the form controls are different. Also you are not creating a FormGroup, you are just trying to display an object as a FormGroup... At least those are issues. Best would be if you create a StackBlitz showcasing your issue.

Comment: You can go with template driven validation in form so when your content_type change adjust [required] attribute of other fields so your validation will be work.